# Google query returns 503

Tags: python, google-search, http-status-code-503

so I've been trying to make a google search request in Python using `requests` and I'm receiving a 503 error.

In any case, this is the code used:

```
params = {
    'q': 'test',
    'safe': 'on',
    'lr': 'lang_en',
    'hl': 'en'
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)'
}

requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
```

Problem is, I used [googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler) in order to perform a google search via terminal and it works perfectly. I thought maybe google blocked my IP or something, but this ain't it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested the code and returned 200, what is your request's response text?

Comment: Apparently it's a CAPTCHA page. But I tested with googler and links2 without receiving any captchas. Is there any way I can avoid/bypass it?

Comment: Enter the correct captcha data!

Comment: Well, how would I do that via a python script? As I said, it only happens when I run the script and not if I enter any google website via remote desktop or command line using `googler`.